# NSUerDefault for saving array of image in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, nsuserdefaults

Hi I'm trying to storing array of images using swift but its not working

i use this for saving

```
     let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(photos, forKey: header)
    defaults.synchronize()
```

and this for loading

```
if let items = defaults.ArrayForKey(header) {
    self.photos = self.photos + items

 }
```

Comment: You can't store UIImage objects in user defaults, you can however store paths to those images instead.

Comment: "You can't store UIImage objects in user defaults" You can but you shouldn't.

Comment: please can you tell me how

Comment: No, I'm not going to. You shouldn't do it.

Comment: ok how can i use the path to store array of images

Answer (score 0):

If `photos` is an array of UIImage, this code will do nothing:

```
 defaults.setObject(photos...)
```

The reason is that UIImage is not a property list type. `defaults` is a property list. See Apple's docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44-SW1